# javascript-CSS Hover Issue over a div

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, hover

I'm working on [Mypage](http://accountabletest.com/) right now, and I've been trying for a long time to make each of the three [one_third] column's divs  containing: text (p), (h5), ('read more') link and Icon, change automatically to white when onMouse (hover).I also need the background color to change to #00673e when onMouse at the same time.

This is my code for each of the column's div issue

HTML

```
[one_third]

[one_half]

<img alt="" src="http://accountabletest.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/imgbox11.jpg">

[/one_half]

[one_half]

<h5>CONSIDER A CARRER IN HIGHWAY CONSTRUCTION</h5>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.Lorem           ipsum dolor sit amet.

<div class="imgB">
<img alt="" src="http://accountabletest.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/moreicon.png" />
</div>
<div class="readmoretext">
<h5><a href='#'>READ MORE</a></h5>
</div>
[/one_half]
[/one_third]
```

CSS

```
.one_third:hover{   
color:white;
background-color: #00673e;
opacity: 0.70;
-moz-opacity: 70%;
-webkit-opacity: 70%;
z-index: 99999999999999;
display: block;

}
```

**I'm open to any solution.**  :) You can see on the link provided that not only the div content does not change to white, but also the img does not get the green overlay expected.(the whole div should be 'covered in #00673e' not only the text background.

Comment: use jquery for apply css properties for your needs.

Comment: @deepus Do you know how to? I'm still not that good with Jquery. I would need that on mouseOver, the icon changes to white (rollover img), text (p) and (h5) change to white, and the background change to #00673e .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this, but then your image won't be in your HTML anymore, not SEO friendly and all..

CSS

```
.imgB {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  background: url("http://accountabletest.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/moreicon.png") no-repeat;
}
.one_third:hover .imgB {
  background: url("http://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/support/ome-artwork/ome-icon-on-white-32.png") no-repeat;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7hcfN/4/)

Comment: I did this also with the img on the left (first half of column) and it worked!. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the color of the `read more` image. If you really want to change the color of that image, you may use `entypo font`, where you can get symbols of your choice.

Comment: Hi,I could make a rollover effect on that image, combining it with the same image but in White. Still I would need the effect to take place while I hover on the div, not only when I hover on the specific Image. Could this be possible with Jquery or javascript?.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should have two images and apply the hover state image when mouse goes on column. I would call the image URL from the CSS then:

```
.one_third img {
 background: url(path/of/image);
}

.one_third:hover img {
 background: url(path/of/hovered/image);
}
```

Comment: which 2 img you suggest me to have? Do you mean a img of the #00673e color overlay?. But what about the text?. Thanks

Comment: Upload two images, one normal and one hover state, then with CSS you can request the URL of the hover image. And text you can change the color attribute on a hover state

Comment: That was what I did. Thank u too!! Support really appreciated ;)